# How to read (get feeds of) different Stack Exchange networks

Tags: support, rss

I follow multiple networks in Stack Exchange where I select Hot/Week/Month to see what I missed.

This is a bit time consuming since I have to switch and click to each one instead of having it delivered to me.

I tried my RSS reader of choice to add the feeds but it defaults to Recent instead of the time period I chose.

Can anyone recommend a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [separate RSS feeds for Hot/Week/Month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its), etc.  EG:

- [travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot)
- [travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/week](https://travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/week)
- [travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/month](https://travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/month)
- [travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured](https://travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured)

---

The API [`/questions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) offers equivalent sorting options for Hot/Week/Month.  EG:

[/questions?order=desc&sort=week&site=travel](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=week&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0Seh_gbZnVfTGRRZ8p4J0H.I5eWQpMouFLr_cY9879QQs8b49fw1dnI&site=travel&run=true)

---

---

Important:  There appears to be a bug in the feed `<link>`s for such pages, so your feed discoverer/reader may not work correctly.

But the hidden-ish feed icon, in the bottom right column, does have the correct RSS/Atom URL:

[image: Location of feed icon]

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip. My RSS reader did not identify those feeds when the URL for the period was entered.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there may be a bug with the `<link>` on those pages.  See the updated answer.